# react useEffect fetch api data gives error TypeError: Cannot read property 'cases' of undefined

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect

```js
import React,{useState,useEffect} from 'react'
import {Bar} from 'react-chartjs-2';

const Chart = ({val}) => {

    
   const [Dataa,setdata] = useState([]);
   useEffect(()=>{
     async function fetchData(){
        const apiresponse =await fetch('https://disease.sh/v3/covid-19/countries');
        const apidata =await apiresponse.json();
        console.log(apidata);
        setdata(apidata);
    }
    fetchData();
},[])


 const chartData = { labels: ['Total Cases', 'Deaths', 'Recovered','Active Cases'],
  datasets: [
    {
      label: 'My First dataset',
      backgroundColor: ['#737270','red','green'],
      borderColor: 'rgba(255,99,132,1)',
      borderWidth: 1,
      hoverBackgroundColor: 'rgba(255,99,132,0.4)',
      hoverBorderColor: 'rgba(255,99,132,1)',
      data: [Dataa && Dataa[val].cases,Dataa[val].deaths,Dataa[val].recovered,Dataa[val].active]     }
  ]
}

    
      return (
        <div>
            <h2>Bar Example</h2>
            <Bar
          data={chartData}
          width={100}
          height={190}
          options={{
            maintainAspectRatio: false
          }}
        />
        </div>
    )
}
export default Chart;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

[Code Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZfYsC.png)

I'm trying to fetch Covid-19 stats to show it in the bar chart but it gives an error on accessing object property.
Val is the index number of the array as an array of objects is begin fetched by api.

Comment: please use the "add script" in the toolbar here in Stackoverflow. So we can help you to debug it directly in the codepad.

Comment: how to add it @suther

Comment: what is the `val` prop here? is it a number?

Comment: val is index number as data fetch from API is an array of object

Comment: @MuhammadTariq check code section in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)

Comment: In the toolbar of your edit-textarea. Move the mouse over the icons, you'll find it. It's called Javascript/HTML/CSS snippet.

Comment: @suther added..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you create the chartData you are passing Dataa and you are not checking the length of it, so when you try to access the `val` position is undefined.

I would suggest checking the length of Dataa before passing it.

```
if (Dataa.length !== 0) {
    const chartData = { labels: ['Total Cases', 'Deaths', 'Recovered','Active Cases'],
    datasets: [
        {
            label: 'My First dataset',
            backgroundColor: ['#737270','red','green'],
            borderColor: 'rgba(255,99,132,1)',
            borderWidth: 1,
            hoverBackgroundColor: 'rgba(255,99,132,0.4)',
            hoverBorderColor: 'rgba(255,99,132,1)',
            data: [Dataa && Dataa[val].cases,Dataa[val].deaths,Dataa[val].recovered,Dataa[val].active]     
        }
   ]
   return (
    <div>
        <h2>Bar Example</h2>
        <Bar
      data={chartData}
      width={100}
      height={190}
      options={{
        maintainAspectRatio: false
      }}
    />
    </div>
   )
  }
} else {
    // Some component while data is loading
}
```

You would probably want to add a spinner or something in order to show that the application is doing something to render the component. In that case, you should return that component if the Dataa.length is equal to zero

Comment: length of Dataa is zero so i what should i do ?? to remove this error

Comment: I've just added a code snippet of a possible solution

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this error because initially `Dataa` is `[]` i.e. empty array.

So if val is 10 and you are accessing `Data && Dataa[10].cases` then it will throw error because there is no object at that position. To fix this you can do something like

```
data: Dataa.length > 0 ? [Dataa[val].cases,Dataa[val].deaths,Dataa[val].recovered,Dataa[val].active] : []
```

Also instead of writing `async` function in your `useEffect`, you can simply do this:

```
fetch("https://disease.sh/v3/covid-19/countries")
  .then((res) => res.json())
  .then((res) => setData(res));
```